# directly post to facebook without share dialog issue

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying a way I can directly post to facebook without dialog that appears once I click share button
actually I wants to bypass that dialog

[image]

previously it was possible but now it is not through facebook javascript sdk

I have search a lot on stackoverflow and facebook sdk documentation but haven't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Earlier it was possible with the `publish_actions` permission, but Facebook removed it. So there is no way anymore to bypass that dialog for user profiles. You can only post to Pages with the API - by using the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions.